# CSS3 animation and transition not smooth

Tags: css, firefox, animation, webkit

I'm trying to develop a slideshow plugin for a project, but I'm running into issues with the CSS3 animations/transitions.

You can view it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/75Sjb/

### What I'm trying to do

- Each slide has both `transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0)` and `transition: all`. This way, slides that aren't active are just outside of the view, to the left, and are ready to be moved around smoothly.
- The active slide also has an animation whose from portion says `transform: translate3d(100%,0,0)`, as well as a new transform property in their CSS as `translate3d(0,0,0)`. So they animate from just right to being snug in the view.

### The problem

**In Webkit**

Although the first time picking a slide is animated properly, every other one after that is botched. The slide going from active to inactive doesn't animate out.

**In Firefox**

In Firefox, the slide going from active to inactive is fine; but the active slide slide in from left (the animation isn't working).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this was an issue with older versions of the browsers, but the animation is working fine now.